# laptop with Windows 10 doesn't boot

Tags: boot, windows-10, lenovo-laptop

So I've been using Windows 10 on my laptop which shipped with windows8 pro 64 bit. It's a Lenovo ThinkPad E530 with 8GB RAM. I used Microsoft Edge browser with like 10 tabs open, one was a YouTube livestream. Upon opening a new tab the browser stopped responding same with the taskbar and i couldn't open the task manager or anything else. It's not the first time this happened, so I forced the computer to power off and tried to start it again, but now i don't even see the Lenovo splash anymore, just a black screen without any bios sounds.

How can I fix this?

Edit: I can't even boot from CD
The Ram cards were removed and a sound code was given. However the RAM were inserted one by one in every slot and still no success with booting any further
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This sounds like either the RAM or the graphics card has failed. You seem to suggest in your comments elsewhere that this laptop is under warranty?

Comment: Unfortunately my warranty expired a few months ago. However even though it's a good assumption that the graphics card failed, I cannot believe it, since it literally worked few seconds ago before I forcefully shut down the laptop. The other reason I think my laptop would be able to use the intel hd graphics. The Ram failure seem more likely, but I can't proof it somehow. The system beep only appears without any Ram inserted.

Comment: Get some cheap, compatible RAM to test with. That will at least let you determine if it is the graphics that has failed. You will only need a single stick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I wanted to throw away my Laptop, I removed my 16 GB SSD where only my OS was booting on. Fortunately my HDD had a copy of my OS on it and could boot after I removed the faulty SSD. The Computer is over 2 years old and one of the first hybrid solutions due to the high price of flash storage, so probably all those factor plus the heat crippled it.

After all my Computer is working again!